# the_content() returning unexpected div wrappers

Tags: the-content

When I call **the_content()** i am getting

```
<div class="page" title="Page 1">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="layoutArea">
            <div class="column">
                <p>my text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would expect just

```
<p>my text</p>
```

I am confused about that. I think I have never had all these wrappers returned. Moreover, I have not found a match for layoutArea in the whole wordpress install, nor in my bootsrtap starter theme.

Any ideas?

--
**UPDATE**: just saw that all those divs were automatically generated by the editor. I was able to remove them via the tinymce text view tab. Still confused, anyway.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the text into the editor from another source? Or write directly in it?

Comment: I might have copied the text from an external source. I am no able to reproduce the problem anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Got it reproduced! You were correct @TheDeadMedic, this error happens when copying-pasting content from an external source. In my case, i was copying it from a pdf, probably exported from indesign or illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

As @TheDeadMedic pointed out, I was copying-pasting text directly from an external source, and that is why the wrappers were in the tinymce as well.

Those divs in my case, were copied from a pdf that was probably exported from illustrator or indesign.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, all those divs surround the `the_content();` function. Theme developers use these divs to wrap the content that's going to be outputted by the `the_content();` function.

Having those divs present there, makes it a whole lot easier to style the content that's coming out from `the_content();`

Bottom line: I don't think you should be removing those divs.

Comment: Thanks Cristian, but those divs were of no benefit to the markup. Even worse i found them nested inside one another. It was kind of messy. I'll com back if i reproduce the problem